# CSS Sticky Footer Margin

Tags: css, footer, sticky

**I do NOT want a FIXED footer, I need a STICKY footer.**

My sticky footer worked fine at first but when the content is at a certain height, there is a margin between the footer and bottom of the page.

Try messing with the browser height and content div height, and you should see where the problem is.

It leaves an awkward margin between the footer and the bottom of the page.

Thank you in advance.

**CSS Code:**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    color:#FFF;
    font:16px Tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100%;
    padding-bottom:-30px;
    width:985px;
}
#content {
    background:#F00;
    height:950px;
}
#footer {
    background:#000;
    border-top:1px solid #00F0FF;
    clear:both;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:100%;
}
#footer span {
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
#push {
    clear:both;
    height:30px;
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bad Footer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="badfooter.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <span>The footer leaves extra space at the bottom when you scroll all the way down. It starts out at the bottom for only the "Above the Fold" section (before scrolling it's at the bottom).</span>
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <a href=""><span>About Us</span></a>
        <span> | </span>
        <a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a>
        <span> | </span>
        <a href=""><span>Home</span></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `position: fixed;` to your `footer` class in your css:

```
#footer {
    background:#000;
    border-top:1px solid #00F0FF;
    clear:both;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed; /*add this new property*/
}
```

-----**UPDATE**-----

If you need a footer that stays at the bottom you need two things:

```
#wrapper {
    /*height:100%;*/   /*you need to comment this height*/
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100%;
    padding-bottom:-30px;
    width:985px;
    position: relative;  /*and you need to add this */
}

#footer {
    background:#000;
    border-top:1px solid #00F0FF;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;  /*use relative position*/
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  /*height:100%;*/   /*you need to comment this height*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;  /* only for Demo purposes */
  padding-bottom: -30px;
  width: 985px;
  position: relative;  /*and you need to add this */
}
#footer {
  background: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #00F0FF;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;  /*use relative position*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <span>The footer leaves extra space at the bottom when you scroll all the way down. It starts out at the bottom for only the "Above the Fold" section (before scrolling it's at the bottom).</span>
  </div>
  <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <a href=""><span>About Us</span></a>
  <span> | </span>
  <a href=""><span>Contact Us</span></a>
  <span> | </span>
  <a href=""><span>Home</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting position to fixed is not a sticky footer... fixed means it will stay on the bottom at all times (despite scrolling). Sticky footers on the other hand are much more complicated. If there is scrolling, you will have to scroll the the bottom to see the footer, otherwise it stay s on the bottom.

Comment: JSFiddle links are broken.

Comment: @Reado Code snippet is now added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: fixed` to the footer class. Note it doesn't work in certain old versions of Internet Explorer. http://jsfiddle.net/kAQyK/

```
#footer {
    background:#000;
    border-top:1px solid #00F0FF;
    clear:both;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

See http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/ for examples how to make it also work in IE

Comment: KEY WORDS: STICKY FOOTER. Setting position to fixed is not a sticky footer... fixed means it will stay on the bottom at all times (despite scrolling). Sticky footers on the other hand are much more complicated. If there is scrolling, you will have to scroll the the bottom to see the footer, otherwise it stay s on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue for ages and nothing seemed to work then I realised that the whitespace I was seeing under my footer was not actually whitespace at all but the overflow from my footer with white text on a white background. All I had to do was to add:

```
overflow:hidden
```

to my footer in my css.

If anyone wants the solution that worked for me then it is the same as http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html but with the added overflow:hidden

Answer (score 0):

**DISPLAY TABLE = NO JS and NO fixed height!**

Works in modern browsers ( IE 8 + ) - I tested it in several browser and it all seemed to work well.

I discovered this solution because I needed a sticky footer without fixed height and without JS. Code is below.

**Explanation:** Basically you have a container div with 2 child elements: a wrapper and a footer. Put everything you need on the page ( exept the footer ) in the wrapper. The container is set to `display: table;` The wrapper is set to `display: table-row;` If you set the html, body and wrapper to `height: 100%`, the footer will stick to the bottom.

The footer is set to `display: table;` as well. This is necessary, to get the margin of child elements. You could also set the footer to `display: table-row;` This will not allow you to set `margin-top` on the footer. You need to get creative with more nested elements in that case.

**The solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/0pzy0Ld1/15/

**And with more content:** http://jantimon.nl/playground/footer_table.html

```css
/* THIS IS THE MAGIC */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body,
#container,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
#container,
#wrapper,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
}
#container,
#footer {
  display: table;
}
#wrapper {
  display: table-row;
}
/* THIS IS JUST DECORATIVE STYLING */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#header,
#footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
#header {
  padding: 1em;
}
#content {
  background: orange;
  padding: 1em;
}
#footer {
  margin-top: 1em; /* only possible if footer has display: table !*/
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      CONTENT
      <br>
      <br>some more content
      <br>
      <br>even more content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>
      FOOTER
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>
      MORE FOOTER
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```