# CSS: Footer appears over main content on browser size shrink

Tags: css, position, z-index, footer, sticky-footer

I created a front-end calculator, and added a "Launch Instructions" button at the bottom of the page. The button expands into a modal when clicked, displaying instructions to operate the calculator.

Here's part of the footer HTML

```
<div id="instructions">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch Instructions
    </button>
```

I `fixed` the `position` of the footer near the bottom of the screen, but I didn't comprehend that it would remain at the same place even when the browser is scaled down, thereby causing the footer to appear over the calculator itself.

Here's the footer css -

```
#instructions {
  position: fixed;
  left: 44%;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1049;
  font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
}

#instructions button {

  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

And here's the complete app on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Nyxx/full/bEwLOy/).

I'm not sure how to make the footer and the "launch instructions" button stay below the calculator, even when the screen is shrunk down. Maybe I need a media query that changes the `z-index` of the `button`?

```
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    #instructions button {
    z-index: -1;
    }

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Sticky Footer Margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868249/css-sticky-footer-margin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do the following:

- Change `z-index` to `1` for `#instructions`.
- Add `z-index: 2` for `#wrapper`.

**CSS**

```css
#instructions {
  z-index: 1;
}
#wrapper {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyGPRR**

Comment: But that puts the button underneath the calculator app. Now, if you scale down the browser, there's no way to click on the button and get the instructions dialogue. I was looking for a way which would ensure that the button always comes *after* the calculator app, and is always clickable.

Comment: @Manish Ah... Now I understood. Okay, I'll check and let you know.

Comment: @Manish Check this out: [**Sticky Footer**](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) is what you require.

Comment: thanks a bunch! Sticky Footer seems to be working great, I'll look through all of the different versions!